# Avoid ClickOnce bootstrapper

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, clickonce

I want to distribute my .NET app via ClickOnce but I also need the VC++ 2008 runtime installed. I know many machines already have the VC++ 2008 runtime so is there any way to detect this from my website? If it's installed I can send them to the .application file. Otherwise I'll send them to setup.exe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good way to do this. There are all sorts of security issues with letting the browser find out all sorts of information about a users machine. The only pre-req with any sort of smarts is the .Net Framework. The fact that it's included in the browser's UserAgent string makes it a little easier.

What I would try to do is to write your app so it can at least launch without the VC++ 2008 runtime. Then you can write your own code to warn the user, download the install, send them to a web page, etc.

ClickOnce is a really nice tool, but pre-reqs are *always* a headache.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just shipping the runtime DLLs with the app itself, instead of using the redist pre-req. Worked like a charm.